# Origin of phrase "hold harmless"?

Tags: phrases, history

Why not use "immune", "exempt", or "unaccountable" rather than the awkward phrase "hold harmless" in legal documents?

Is there historical context for the use of this language?

Comment: Historical context? What else but legal formulas that held up in court yesterday? There is only history to blame for legalese like *Time is of the essence*. Of course if you deliver a wedding cake slightly late, a day after the wedding, then you are in breach of contract.

Comment: Legal writing depends on precise use of words, not pretty or modish use of words. You don't vary words just for the sake of it; you want to use the same words for the same meaning, or else people will ask why you changed it.

Comment: to hold harmless is only used in legal English, particularly in contracts where they are saying a person or company will not be liable for something; they will be held harmless. To absolve of responsibility: https://thetrcompany.com/en/indemnify-and-hold-harmless-in-legal-english/#:~:text=Black's%20Law%20Dictionary%20treats%20indemnify,from%20the%20transaction%3B%20INDEMNIFY.%E2%80%9D

Comment: @Lambie Right, but why not state "Company X will not be liable" instead of "Company X will be held harmless", which seems unclear and isn't grammatically correct.

Comment: Because the idea of holding refers to a proceeding or situation: The courts "hold" this or that. You can read the full definition in Black's Law Dictionary. It's like: I hold you  responsible for X. Then, it would have to be shown to be true.